# Jquery ajax POST php session to determine active page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm running CakePHP 2.5.X and we have the CMS setup where pages can be created in the admin, and then associated to the navigation. I've also added the option to setup pages as links, so we do not have duplicate content/pages. We found the issue that if we create a page (A) as the parent, another parent page (B) then have a child page (C) with the content with it's parent as A, then create this same page (D) with no content but set a URL variable so that the navigation system knows to make this a link to C.

Example HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li data-id="1"><a href="/a">A
        <ul>
            <li data-id="2" parent-page="1"><a href="/c">C</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="3"><a href="/b">B
        <ul>
            <li data-id="4" parent-page="3"><a href="/c">D</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The issue, when D is clicked you are then sent to page C, which then sets the parent page A as active. To prevent this and to ensure that B and D remain as the active links (class="active"), I've used jquery and ajax to post to a php script which then writes the page ids to a session that I can read upon page load and set the appropriate page to active. However it does not seem to work. In chrome I have no issues, its FireFox, IE, Safari, etc that are giving me issues. Essentially it does not work or only partial works.

```
$("ul.child li a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/users/setSession/", 
        data : {
            current_page_id: $(this).parent().attr('data-id'), 
            page_parent_id: $(this).parent().attr('page-parent')
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
    <?php if ($this->Session->check('User.User.id') == 1) { ?>
        alert(msg);
    <? } ?>
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas or other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to simply have duplicate pages with different names and just do a no-index. A shame that we could not get this working in any browser but Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the following solution. Append a class="active" on current_page_id and parent_page_id.

```
$("ul.child li a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault() //preventing the anchor clicked event
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/users/setSession/", 
    data : {
        current_page_id: $(this).parent().attr('data-id'), 
        parent_page_id: $(this).parent().attr('parent-page') //changed_by_me
    }
}).done(function(msg) {
    ///////////////Added following lines////////////////
    var activeLi = $('ul.nav').find('li[data-id="'+current_page_id+'"]');
    activeLi.addClass('active').closest('li[data-id="'+parent_page_id+'"]').addClass('active');
    //$('ul.nav').find('li[data-id="'+parent_page_id+'"]').addClass('active');

<?php if ($this->Session->check('User.User.id') == 1) { ?>
    alert(msg);
<? } ?>
});
});
```

Comment: Once the link is clicked the page redirects. So assigning the active class to the li item once the ajax call is done would be pointless as the page would then reload and those changes would be lost...